# Recaptcha PostAsync throwing System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, react-google-recaptcha

Tried implementing a google Recaptcha , Locally it is working very fine . But when deployed to other server (Through Octopus) it throws the exception. Unable to find the cause. Happens on PostAsync call .Please needed help.

```
  using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())

{
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this.ValidationTimeoutMiliseconds);                    



                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                   { "secret", Secret },
                   { "response", value as string }
                };



                LogHelper.WriteLog("Start: Recaptcha requestdata is about to post to google...");
                var response = client.PostAsync("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                LogHelper.WriteLog("End: Recaptcha requestdata is posted successfully");



                var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GRecaptchaValidationResponseModel>(responseString);



                if (responseModel.ErrorCodes != null && responseModel.ErrorCodes.Contains("invalid-input-secret"))
                    LogHelper.WriteLogAsync("Invalid input secret for reCaptcha. Please configure in advanced settings parameters for Forms.");



                return responseModel.Success;
 }
```

**throw exception :**
An exception have occured while posting to google recaptcha : System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Comment: Have you tried researching the error? Most likely TLS 1.2 related.

Comment: Try changing to only TLS1.2 : System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @jdweng did try as suggested , no luck

Comment: Make sure you are using latest version (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro#devguide).  What verision of Net are you using?  Depending on version of Net you can be doing the TLS in Net or the Operating System.  If you are using a mobile device you may need to upgrade the kernel.

Comment: Google switched from HTTP to HTTPS (secure) a few years ago and no requires HTTPS.  The error message looks like an error when you try to use HTTPS and the server wants HTTP.  So I suspect you are using an old version of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Resolved, There was a firewall issue blocking in server . On resolving , worked fine.